# How qsort modify pointer to string?

Tags: c, pointers

The implementation of `qsort` in glibc modify the array of pointer by swap function as defined like this:

```
#define SWAP(a, b, size)                              \
  do                                          \
    {                                         \
      register size_t __size = (size);                        \
      register char *__a = (a), *__b = (b);                   \
      do                                      \
    {                                     \
      char __tmp = *__a;                              \
      *__a++ = *__b;                              \
      *__b++ = __tmp;                             \
    } while (--__size > 0);                           \
    } while (0)
```

...See the full code [here](http://www.cs.umaine.edu/~chaw/200801/capstone/n/qsort.c.html)...

Say, I've declared the array of pointer like this: (I know pointer strings cannot be modified).

```
  char *a[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"},
         *lo = (char*)a,
         *hi = &lo[2];
    SWAP(lo, hi, 4);   // Doesn't work.
```

In short, I want to know how `qsort` sort array of pointer to string. As far as I know, array of pointer cannot be modified. It can only point to other pointer.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What happens? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: How qsort use that SWAP function to swap the array of string pointer (char *a[]).

Comment: What are you expecting `lo` and `hi` to point to?

Comment: I want to swap, (lo <-> hi).

Comment: Do you want this output `{"three", "two", "one", "four"}`?

Comment: Yes, but by SWAP method of qsort. I want to know how qsort swap array of pointers to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initializations of `lo` and `hi` are incorrect. They should be:

```
    char *lo = (char*)&a[0],
         *hi = (char*)&a[2];
```

This will swap the values of `lo` and `hi`.  Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a, b, size)                                \
    do                                                  \
        {                                               \
            register size_t __size = (size);            \
            register char *__a = (a), *__b = (b);       \
            do                                          \
                {                                       \
                    char __tmp = *__a;                  \
                    *__a++ = *__b;                      \
                    *__b++ = __tmp;                     \
                } while (--__size > 0);                 \
        } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    char *lo = (char*)&a[0], *hi = (char*)&a[2];
    SWAP(lo, hi, sizeof(*lo));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("a[%d] = %s\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a[0] = three
a[1] = two
a[2] = one
a[3] = four
```

Suppose the string memory is initially like this, starting from address 1000:

```
one\0two\0three\0four\0
```

The values of the array are:

```
a[0] = 1000 -> one
a[1] = 1004 -> two
a[2] = 1008 -> three
a[3] = 1014 -> four
```

After the `SWAP`, the string memory is unchanged, but the array is now:

```
a[0] = 1008 -> three
a[1] = 1004 -> two
a[2] = 1000 -> one
a[3] = 1014 -> four
```

Comment: It works, but one question. How SWAP function swap these strings character by character. As far as I know, pointer to strings cannot be modified.

Comment: Why can't a pointer to strings be modified? Anything that isn't `const` can be modified.

Comment: You're confusing pointers to strings with the contents of literal strings.

Comment: @ashish2expert  You cannot modify literal strings. In fact, you should use `char const *a[] = ...` to have correct type for `a`.

Comment: It's not modifying the literal strings. It's only swapping the pointers. So now `a[0]` points to where `a[2]` used to point, and vice versa.

Comment: Okay, I have to think it more, before I question you. By the way, thanks for the answer. Your answer really helpful to me.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the answer, maybe that will help you.